# Concourse prevent background processes from being stopped if job is canceled

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, yaml, background-process, concourse

I have a `Concourse` job which internally runs shell scripts for every `task.yml` of the pipeline. One of these scripts I would like to continue executing even if the job was manually aborted.

Is there a way to accomplish this in `Concourse`? Either controlling the way of process killing on `Concourse` level or running shell scripts in background without `Concourse` being able to terminate them. Or separating this process to be executed by a different, independent node.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of the [**ensure**](https://concourse-ci.org/ensure-step-hook.html) step hook? If the parent step succeeds, fails, errors, or is aborted, the contents within the **ensure** step hook will still run. The parent step could be an empty or informational **task**.

Comment: This is a good option. However, if the build is aborted during the child task execution then no matter the child is under ensure step hook it still gets aborted. I need a way in which irrespective of when and which stage the build is aborted this step to keep running. Any other ideas?